# sed command to replace part of file

Tags: bash, sed, command-line-interface

Hi I want to replace a part of my `/etc/sysconfig/file`
It consists:

```
OPTIONS='--para'

CERT_PATH=/etc/cert
```

I want to replace `OPTIONS='--para'` by `OPTIONS='--para --para2 172.0.0.0/16'`

So I tried:

```
sudo sed -i 's/"OPTIONS='--para'"/"`OPTIONS='--para --para2 172.0.0.0/16'"/' /etc/sysconfig/file
```

But the error:

```
edit the /etc/sysconfig/file
sed: -e expression #1, char 88: unknown option to `s'
```

Can someone help me to correct this sed-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo sed -i "s#OPTIONS='--para'#OPTIONS='--para --para2 172.0.0.0/16'#" /etc/sysconfig/file
```

Comment: tried it, it gave no error but there wasn't a change. I only saw the output of the original file

Comment: Add back the `-i` option to do in-place edits.

Comment: @Jenson you need the -i flag along with the sudo. I didn't test the above command and thus avoided the -i flag as you will be testing it first. Now I have tested it and added both sudo and -i.

Comment: Thanks, the ip contains a '/' which I did not saw. That was the reason it wasn't working